# Sharing CAN bus to two microcontrollers without increasing bus load

Tags: can

I have 2 MCUs in one PCB that I want to communicate via CAN to other devices far away.
Instead of adding two CAN transceivers and becoming two node loads to the network, I thought to combine the two MCUs to a single CAN Transceiver using an AND gate on the TXD line, like in the attached picture (that I am trying to upload...).

It seems okay, but there is a chance I am missing something.

Looking forward for the acute eyes from this selected group.
Thank you in advance
-Augusto

[image: ANDing CAN TXs]

Comment: Welcome, an AND gate seems a bit too simplistic for your application. Your Tx messages are made out of bytes (sequences of logical 0 and 1) and an AND gate needs a logical 1 on each input. Furthermore, what if both of your MCU send a message at the same time?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to AND two serial buses together, in any context, CAN or otherwise. That's not how digital communication works...

Comment: @Lundin Quite right; a logical OR will be much better if you want to connect high-idling communication buses together behind a single transceiver.

Comment: Thanks all. Still, CAN bus uses dominant and resessive method. All nodes keep the TX line (on the MCU side) at level High, until it needs to insert a 0 on the CAN bus. The AND gate works because only one MCU (CAN controller inside MCU) will be transmitting zeros. All devices tied to CAN will receive what is going on in the CAN bus.

Comment: Thanks @Justme and others. An OR gate would block the MCUs to transmit, because one MCU would be always at level 1, forcing the OR output at 1. This strategy of ANDing should work, but I never saw any application suggesting this. Now that the idea is public, cannot be patented, but if no one finds a flaw, it could be used to save space and performance. Imagine that an intra-board CAN, between several MCUs, could be implemented by ANDing all TXs and connecting the output of the AND to all RXs.

Comment: @AEKE Ahh yes sorry AND is more correct since TXD pins idle high. I am sure there is a lot of prior art for ANDing signals so it would be unpatentable anyway. I hope you were not serious about the patentability of using an AND gate in context of combining data from multiple MCUs for single transceiver. The problem is that many CAN drivers have a timeout feature so if both MCUs transmit then the scenario is not identical to two separate transmitters. Also why not simply let one MCU handle the comms to CAN and communicate privately with the second MCU.

Comment: @AEKE Your idea actually looks correct, and I really can't say what would go wrong if you AND-wired all CAN interfaces without even using transceivers on a single-board design. Thing is: nobody does that because CAN is made to solve problems you don't have in this case: longer distance transmission. If you want intra-board communication, everybody goes with SPI or I2C, as it's easier and cheaper. However, here is somebody who tried it: https://community.nxp.com/t5/Other-NXP-Products/Question-about-CAN-connection-without-transceiver/m-p/1367881 , in a similar way to you.

Comment: @AEKE I could find an official app note from siemens about this, acutally: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/28831/siemens_AP2921.pdf

Comment: I think it can work but it depends on your CAN transceiver. If one MCU hangs then neither of them can communicate even if CAN transceiver has jabber timeout for safety. Which CAN transceiver you plan to use?

Comment: @Justme, and dim, thanks for the replies. The application has two MCUs to talk to a CAN network. Inter-MCU communication was the first approach, but the transport delay could kill the safety objectives. Thanks dim for the app. Nice to see this was not a fully crazy idea. Yet, as Justme pointed out, if one MCU would hang on dominant state it would cripple the other MCU to access CAN. The CAN transceivers have embedded timeout to automatically isolate faulty nodes. I am thankful for this reminder. I would need a timeout feature before the AND, too.

Comment: Note that, simply adding another CAN transceiver does not work because the limitation in number of nodes, speed and bus length.